# Filtering HTML Table On Client But Export To CSV Showing Whole Table

Tags: javascript, html

I am filtering my HTML table on the client side using the following JS code:

```
function searchAwards(){
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("firstName");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("award_entry");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

This works well and appropriately filters the table on the page. I have also implemented a couple of functions that export the HTML table to CSV. The code that performs this function is:

```
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
}

function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}
```

This code sends a .csv file to my downloads but it always shows all of the records in the table regardless of the filtering done on the client. Is there a way to send only the filtered data being displayed on the client to CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that hidden/filtered elements are not added to the csv result. :)

```js
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // Don't add the row to the csv if it's hidden due to filtering.
        if (rows[i].style.display === "none") continue;
        
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}
```